# No redirect to deep link page after installing app from AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking

The users of the app I'm working on can open it from deep link. It works fine if the app is already installed, but if not, users are redirected to App Store, and, after installing the app, they get to the main registration page, not to the one handled in the deep link. If there any way to open the page handled in deep link after installing the app from App Store? And I wonder, how it works? I mean how App Store know that this app was installed from deep link and it how should proceed?